Save customer email via WPForms on checkbox marking when placing the Woocommerce order
Does anyone know the way to save the customer's email & process it with WPForm, when they mark the checkbox to sign up for the newsletter on the payment/order screen?
I have Google Sheet plugin in WPForms and would like to save those addresses, if the checkbox is marked.
I know how to add the form (checkbox) with hooks, but not sure about setting up actual email string transfer to the spreadsheet.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
